# find dataframe2 colum in dataframe1 column similar to the sql like operator and list the result from dataframe2 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

xls1='C:\\Downloads\\Allparts.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(xls1,sheet_name='Data')

df=df['Part Number'].head(10)

xls2='C:\\Downloads\\Part_Details.xlsx'

dz = pd.read_excel(xls2,sheet_name='Data')

dz=dz.drop(dz.columns[[2, 4]], axis = 1)

dz=dz.drop(dz.columns[[3, 4, 5]], axis = 1)

for fd in df:

        if dz['Name'].str.contains(fd):
           print(dz['Name'],fd)
```

[image]

xls2:
[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Below code solved my purpose. Hope it helps others.

fdf=pd.dataframe()

for zd in dz['Name']:

```
 for fd in df['Part Number']:

           if str(zd) in str(fd):

               res=df[df['Part Number']==fd]
               fdf = pd.concat([fdf, res], axis=0)
```